Where to find Ball and Revolute Joints with friction
I am new to design. Where do I find bearing joints that stay put? Suppliers? I am looking for.

A ball joint that has friction so that it stays put after it is moved. I was looking at modeling one with a 3d printer but I am worried the joint would not last so I am looking for either some sort of durable plastic or metal insert or something where I have a joint that can move +-80 degrees in all directions but has some decent wear properties and also stays put without flopping around.
The same thing but with a revolute joint where it revolves around a single axis.


McMaster Carr has quite a selection.  Possibly the Positioning Arm subsection.
https://www.mcmaster.com/products/ball-and-socket-joints/
